# How to make emoji bigger in Messages

Tags: macos, messages, emoji

I just upgraded to Mavericks 10.9.3 from Mountain Lion and the emoticons / emoji are quite small in Messages. Sometimes I can't even tell the difference between one and another emoji.

When I open the emoji panel they are bigger, at the size I was accustomed to in 10.8. You can see in the picture the size they appear in a message, as compared to the panel.

[image]

I've tried making the font bigger in Message's preferences, but the emoji won't change their size either.

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround I've found is to use accessibility zoom; old man style.

The problem persists in Yosemite 10.10.3 with the new Emoji picker.

Answer (score 0):

To make a larger emoji in an email message, I tried this work-around with my Mac.  Copy and paste the desired emoji into Text Edit.  Using (Command +) I enlarged it to the desired size, then captured it with Command, shift, 4 and pasted it into the email. Yeah, it's a pain, but it works.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not sending bigger emojis, but seeing which emojis I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround might be to copy & paste from a website like http://getemoji.com which shows emojis at a larger size and has a search feature. I assume there are many similar websites.

It seems there is no *good* built-in option, including up to OSX Sierra (10.12.6):

- The [full character viewer](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macos/macos-sierra-emoji-character-viewer-popup-expanded.png) that you get to when clicking the icon in the top right of the [simpler emoji focused viewer](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macos/macos-sierra-emoji-character-viewer-popup.png) has an option to change the character size in 3 steps (under the gear icon in the top left), but unfortunately it doesn't make a big difference and it only applies to the full viewer.
- Accessibility zooming (ctrl + mouse wheel) doesn't increase the resolution of the icons, so it's not the same quality as emojis rendered at a larger size.

Answer (score 0):

While typing in Messages, Mail, and other programs, select Edit, then Emoji and Symbols from the menu bar, and you will see a larger emoji-picker window appear. You can inseet emojis from this larger window instead of having to use the tiny emoji-picker accessible via the text-input field. This is how I get around this problem in 10.10.3

Answer (score -2):

In TextEdit, I typed a sentence.  I then brought up the Character Viewer (I don't seem to be able to get to emoji any other way, though using Mavericks 10.9.3 on a 2014 iMac), and placed an emoji character into the sentence--the bactrian camel, in this instance.  I then selected the emoji in the sentence I wrote in TextEdit and went to the Font Size menu in TextEdit.  I chose 36, and the emoji enlarged to size 36.  I then selected again and enlarge to size 144.  Worked both times.

Comment: The question is about Messages, not Text Edit

Comment: I was hoping that one could then copy and paste the enlarged emoji into Messages, but no dice.